# Maven release and versions maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, maven-release-plugin, versions-maven-plugin

What is the numbering/versioning strategy for dependencies when doing snapshots/releases?

A team of 15 developers,20 Maven parent projects = total 70+ POMs including child module POMs. Currently there  are a lot of dependencies where most of these 70 depend on one or the other.

### Past:

All POMS have `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` as their version and also under dependencies tags.It gets uploaded to Nexus repo with `mvn deploy`.

### Present:

We started doing `mvn release` recently. So all 20 parent POMs are now `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT` and release ver `1.0.0` for all of them lies in Nexus.All `<dependencies>` tags now point to `1.0.0`

### Problem:

**Developers** don't want to point to release versions. They need bleeding edge development version `1.0.X-SNAPSHOT` from their peers whether its unstable or not.

**SCM** wants to point to `RELEASE` versions only as he has to do a `mvn release` once a week which will fail as it points to snapshot versions.

### Question:

Now I know the [version plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) , but the question is, what do I put in the POM so that both parties are satisfied by running their own version of `mvn versions:` command. Preferably, the POMs should point to SNAPSHOTS so 15 people are happy, and when SCM does the release, he can run a `mvn versions:something` and everything gets converted to `RELEASE` versions in place of `SNAPSHOTS`. Then back to SNAPSHOTS for developers.

Comment: is this a single big-bang release, or are all the separate modules released independently? IOW how many projects does the SCM run `mvn release:prepare release:perform` on in order to cut the release

Comment: 20 projects released one by one . each would have 2-15 modules like projA-parent, projA-jar,projA-war,projA-Ear.. so total POMs modified by the release plugin would be 100+, but I am ok to do 20 iterations of a solution if there is one..

Answer (score 3):

I am putting this as an answer, even though at present this is not quite working answer.

When I added the [`completionGoals`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#completionGoals) configuration option in the Maven Release Plugin, my aim was to enable the work-flow where development used version ranges, but that releases would be pinned to concrete versions only.

One of the enabling goals that was added to the Versions Maven Plugin was the [`versions:resolve-ranges`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/resolve-ranges-mojo.html) goal. What is missing is a way to unresolve those ranges again afterwards.

We don't really have anywhere safe to stash the originating ranges that the release plugin will not object to or clean up before we need it again.

The closest solution I have thought of is to inject [XML PI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_Instruction)'s beside the version containing the version range... in such a situation, the `pom.xml` would get transformed from, e.g.

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
      <artifactId>manchu</artifactId>
      <version>[1.2.3,2.0)</version>
    </dependency?
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

to

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
      <artifactId>manchu</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.7</version>
      <?versions-maven-plugin allowed-version-range="[1.2.3,2.0)"?>
    </dependency?
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
</project>
```

by ensuring that the [`preparationGoals`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#preparationGoals) included the `versions:resolve-ranges` goal... (Note: the versions plugin might have to fork a third Maven to work around the lack of `pom.xml` reloading in order to have the `clean verify` be meaningful, though `resolve-ranges` is supposed to resolve in the exact version that the build is working with, so it shouldn't be an issue).

Then in [`completionGoals`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#completionGoals) you have the (as yet unimplemented) versions-maven-plugin goal that removes the XML PI's and puts the ranges back in place.

There are a number of issues preventing this at present:

- Unsure if the Maven Release Plugin's pom rewriting will remove the XML PI's (needs testing to confirm)
- The XML parsing library in versions-maven-plugin is hacky at best, and a better solution is needed to enable the XML PI injection
- My son demands attention, leaving very little time for me to attend to these issues.

However, you might be able to codge something together.

1. Set `completionGoals` to something like `versions:use-next-snapshots versions:commit`
2. Run your releases like so `mvn versions:use-releases versions:commit scm:commit release:prepare release:perform install`

So what should happen:

- We switch the `-SNAPSHOT`s to releases
- We commit the change to SCM
- We start the release preparation
- When the `pom.xml` is transformed to the next development version, we also advance the dependencies (using the fact that all our dependencies had the exact same command (with the `install` at the end) so their next `-SNAPSHOT` is already in the local repository, so they will get advanced for us *automatically* (in **theory**)) and we rely on `release:prepare` to commit the changes for us.
- The release is performed as normally
- We install the next development `-SNAPSHOT` into the local repo so that all the down-stream projects will get their version of this updated when they run `versions:use-next-snapshots`

The above is slightly error prone... I'd far prefer if I could offer you the version range based solution, but, well right now this is the best solution I can see.

Comment: interesting .. let me give it some thought, though I am sort of surprised that there is no existing approach for this. I presumed this would be a common enough quandry for "Maven people"

Comment: Keep in mind, that most people dislike [developing on top of sand](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2012/12/should-you-deploy-snapshots.html) so the issue you have is your developers like building on top of sand and therefore keep snapshot dependencies in trunk as a matter of course.

Comment: I know that its a best practice to not do this. But its only that - a best practice. Now if my RELEASE is happening once in 3 weeks, and in between the developer needs the latest "base-utility-project" which is "base" for everything, they cannot afford surprises 3 weeks later !! I'd like to call it analogous to "code merge" where the sooner you have the other guys' code, the better it is as a thumb rule. Here it is sort of a merge for my library JAR, that's all. And I got to manage it somehow.

Comment: Well, your question seems to imply that living on sand is a permanent part of the development process. The best practice in such cases is either: to cut regular milestones of the upstream dependency; or to refactor the upstream dependency into an API and IMPL. The API should be stable between sprints, and newer versions of the IMPL should only fix bugs or introduce new features, hence you don't need the latest. Use a CI system (e.g. Jenkins) to run builds on both the current code as in SCM, and integration builds with the latest bleeding edge shifting sand dependencies.

Comment: You could have Jenkins cut milestone releases of all your stuff every night, and advance versions automatically. Alternatively, if they are *that* tightly coupled, perhaps they should be in the same multi-module build and then the `-SNAPSHOT` dependency will be updated by the Maven release plugin automatically when releasing the multi-module project as one.

Comment: thanks alot for your inputs.. but this is what I am testing now
1. Use `dependencyManagement` in 20 Parent POMs
2. Use `dependencies` in the rest 50 or so module POMs
3. Use a pre-build step in Jenkins `mvn versions:use-releases -DallowSnapshots=true`
4. `mvn release` as the main build step
5. Use a post-build step in Jenkins `mvn versions:use-latest-snapshots -DallowSnapshots=true`
6. Repeat steps 3-5 for 20 projects in Jenkins. Maybe automate that too with script/CLI. 

In short, convert all snapshot dependencies to Release before the actual release, then after the release convert back to SS

Comment: this solution which I was testing works.. with some modifications. I'll post a proper answer on how to do it with Jenkins